# refactoring 2 closely coupled methods

Tags: f#, refactoring

Ok so I'm making a mockup of a distributed system.
each instance of  mClass (object) is used by 1 thread. Mutable data can't be passed between mClass objects
This is a example of code analogous to what I have:

```
type mClass (mID:id)=
    member this.ID=mID

    let resolve : id->mClass  =... //This function turns IDs into the objects they represnt
    ...
    let managementInfo = ref Some mutableData

    //this should only ever be called by the GiveControl method.
    private member this.TakeControl (frozenData) =
        let defrostedData = ... //a variable that works out the unfrozen version of the frozenData
        managementInfo := Some defrostedData


    ///This is a helper that ensure that when ever someone else is told to take control 
    ///that all my internal data and any functions i need to call to tell others are done
    ///And convert the data a nonmutable form 
    ///(Mutable data can not be tranfered between different instances of of mClass (objects), 
    ///as this is a mockup of a distributed system, where the instances of mClass can't
    ///@param: nID this ID of the object we are giving control to
    ///@param: callbacks: a list of functions to call to tell other objects i've given control 
    private member this.GiveControl nID (callbacks: list<id->unit>) =
        let updateInternalData = ... //A function to upate my internal state
        updateInternalData;
        ignore (List.map (fun f-> f nID) callbacks);
        let freezeData data= ... //a function make our mutableData into nonmutable data
        let frozenData = (!managemenInfo).Value|>freezeData 
        managemenInfo:=None;
        (nID|>resolve).TakeControl (frozenData)

    ...
```

private member this.GiveControl was originally declared:
let giveControl
but it made the compiler complain about mis-declaring a new type, until i changed it to a private method.

The question is, how can I re factor this code,
to merge the two methods into one. (or atleast make GiveControl only callable from within this object (real private as it were) and TakeControl only callable from GiveControl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you orinally had giveControl as a let, this is excactly what you need to do.
things delare with a let are truely private values. they can't be accessed from outside your object.

The it is a requirement of classes in F# that lets are delared before members.
also F# is not single passover for class methods,
thus your let can reference any method you need.

type mClass (mID:id)=
    member this.ID=mID

```
let resolve : id->mClass  =... //This function turns IDs into the objects they represnt
...
let managementInfo = ref Some mutableData
let giveControl nID (callbacks: list<id->unit>) =
...

private member this.TakeControl (frozenData) =
    ...
```

This doesn't fix your second problem, however

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to protect yourself from yourself? Even this version involves mutating state of another mClass (you are calling TakeControl from the giving thread not the taking thread). Maybe instead of worrying about passing mutable information you should use a message passing system and be sane about the information use (i.e. null references after passing).

If you truly want internal access to something than a let binding is the way to go. You could move these control methods to a separate class, and a let to create each instance per mClass (or a parameter). However there is no way to guarantee the last part about TakeControl being callable from GiveControl, unless you somehow pass the responsibility of Giving and Taking onto the receiving end.